# Mod_rewite - do these rewrite rules work?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Help, please.  Can you tell me if this is the correct code to perform the following rewrites?  I can't test this particular change like I would like.

This company has four domains in a single apache instance.

**I only want to affect one - test.example.com.**

I need this block to do the following:

1. if the host is test.example.com, any call to / needs to go to /admin/index.php
2. if the host is test.example.com, any call to http needs to go to https

```
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^/admin/index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /admin/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks so much,
Lynn

UPDATE:

How about something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.lifestylepubs\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
RewriteRule  ^/$ /admin/index.php
```

Comment: `!^test\.example\.com` (with a `!` prefix) is a _negated_ regex. So, this matches when the `Host` is _not_ `test.example.com`, which would seem to be the opposite of what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If your apache server serves 4 domains, then I would assume each domain is in its own vhost. If not, that's the first thing I would fix.

Then you can put your rewrite rule in the appropriate vhost configuration and not having to worry about much.

Otherwise your rewrite rules just need:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}       =test.example.com
RewriteRule  ^/$                 /admin/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}       =test.example.com        
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
```

Comment: You're not wrong, and I don't disagree.  Totally singing to the choir.  Unfortunately the bosses dictating my schedule have set the priorities the way they are.  I can't take the time right at this moment to do that, although I will asap.  Today tho, I need to get test switched over to https.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it forced all domains to redirect to HTTPS, and in addition the URL ended up as https://prod.example.comprod.example.com

Comment: Maybe something like.... (see updated question)

Comment: See edit. I know that works as I use this myself somewhere.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.example.com` - You should ideally be testing against `HTTP_HOST` here, not `SERVER_NAME` (you are already using `HTTP_HOST` in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_). Whilst `SERVER_NAME` defaults to the same as `HTTP_HOST`, this is not necessarily the case. If `UseCanonicalName On` is set then `SERVER_NAME` is the value assigned to the `ServerName` directive, so this wouldn't work if `test.example.com` was a `ServerAlias`.